# Error in implementation with interface

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I'm sorry for my English, I'm having trouble with an implementation.

I have an abstract class with only one method that implements an interface

```
    package br.com.teste;

public abstract class Test implements IDefault
{
    @Override
    public String test1()
    {
        return "Test method Class";
    }
}
```

I have an interface with the abstract class method

```
package br.com.teste;

public interface IDefault
{
    public String test1();
}
```

And I have a second interface that extends to first one and has one more method

```
package br.com.teste;

public interface ITest extends IDefault
{
    public String test2();
}
```

Interceptor

```
package br.com.teste.intercept;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import net.bytebuddy.dynamic.TargetType;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.AllArguments;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Origin;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.RuntimeType;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.SuperCall;


public class ProxyInvocationHandler
{
    @RuntimeType
    public static Object intercept(@SuperCall Callable<?> callable, @Super(proxyType = TargetType.class) Object delegate, @Origin Class<?> clazz, @Origin Method method, @AllArguments Object[] args) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println(method.getName());
        //
        return null;
    }
}
```

The code i use

```
package br.com.teste;

import br.com.teste.intercept.ProxyInvocationHandler;
import net.bytebuddy.ByteBuddy;
import net.bytebuddy.ClassFileVersion;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodDelegation;
import net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers;


public class Main
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        try
        {
            ClassLoader classLoader = Main.class.getClassLoader();
            Class<? extends ITest> proxyType = (Class<? extends ITest>) new ByteBuddy(ClassFileVersion.JAVA_V8).subclass(Test.class).implement(ITest.class).method(ElementMatchers.any()).intercept(MethodDelegation.to(ProxyInvocationHandler.class)).make().load(classLoader).getLoaded();
            ITest test = proxyType.newInstance();
            //
            System.out.println(test.test1());
            System.out.println(test.test2());
            //
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: None of [net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.TargetMethodAnnotationDrivenBinder$Record@4d8c5c64] allows for delegation from public abstract java.lang.String br.com.teste.ITest.test2()
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.MethodDelegationBinder$Processor.bind(MethodDelegationBinder.java:827)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodDelegation$Appender.apply(MethodDelegation.java:1035)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod$WithBody.applyCode(TypeWriter.java:614)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod$WithBody.applyBody(TypeWriter.java:603)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod.apply(TypeWriter.java:521)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default$ForCreation.create(TypeWriter.java:4102)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default.make(TypeWriter.java:1612)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.subclass.SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.make(SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.java:174)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.subclass.SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.make(SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.java:155)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase.make(DynamicType.java:2560)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase$Delegator.make(DynamicType.java:2662)
    at br.com.teste.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

Comment: Shouldn't `Test` implement `ITest`? The error sounds like `bytebuddy` doesn't find a way to call the method on your instance, which is definitively the case if it doesn't implement the right interface.

Comment: I agree with BeyelerStudios. Your class Test implements IDefault and not ITest. Therefore you only have access to your method test1().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `test2` method is abstract down the hierarchy and it cannot be invoked with a super method invocation. Therefore, the `@SuperCall` annotation cannot be bound to an instance where Byte Buddy rejects the method as a possible binding candidate. You can set the `@SuperCall(nullIfImpossible = true)` to have `null` bound to the method or add another interception method with a weaker requirement which Byte Buddy considers its second choice if your method cannot be bound.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `Test` only implements the `IDefault` interface which provides method `test1`.
It does not implement the `ITest` interface, which declares method `test2`. If it implemented `ITest` interface, it would automatically mean that it implemented the `IDefault` as well.

For this reason, you get an exception mentioning that there is no method `test2` available in your created subclass of `Test`.

Answer (score 0):

The application is correct, the byte-ddudy needs to use the methods that are declared in the abstract class.
Methods that are just in the byte-duddy interface created blank.
As I'm intercepting all the executed methods, for these blank generate a dynamic return.
I used cglib for this and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

When I remove "@SuperCall" the parameter from the Interceptor method the application works

```
@RuntimeType
public static Object intercept(@Origin Method method, @AllArguments Object[] args, @Super Object delegate) throws Exception
{
    System.out.println(method.getName());
    //
    return null;
}
```